# Ionic 2 - Custom component not rendering as expected

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to build a feedback input component, it works great for angular 2 apps but when I try to use it with Ionic component as `ng-content` the input doesn't render as it should. I've already imported `IONIC_DIRECTIVES` as mentioned in other posts.

Using Angular `2.0.0-rc.1` and Ionic `2.0.0-beta.7`

Custom component (simplified):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-feedback',
  directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `

  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <span>should render this..</span>

  `
})
export class AppFeedback {

}
```

Usage:

```
@Page({
...
directives: [AppFeedback],
template: `

    <ion-content>
        <form (ngSubmit)="attemptLogin()" [ngFormModel]="form">
            <ion-item primary>
                <ion-label floating>Usuário</ion-label>
                <app-feedback>
                    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="cred.username" 
                        [ngFormControl]="form.controls.email" type="email" ></ion-input>
                </app-feedback>
            </ion-item>        
        </form>
    </ion-content>

`
})
export class LoginPage { ... }
```

this is how the screen renders:

[image]

No error is shown on console

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "the input doesn't render as it should"?

Comment: Updated with a screenshot @ThierryTemplier

Comment: Also added angular and ionic versions @ThierryTemplier